# Electrical Resistance between end points of a square grid is maximum using graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a $n\times n$ square grid with a $1 \Omega$ resistor on each edge. Why is the resistance between the $(0,0)$ and $(n,n)$ the lowest( Previously was highest)? I am interested in the general $d$-dimension grid too.

I would like some way of seeing this without explicitly calculating the resistance for any two pairs of points.

Comment: for finite grids, you can exactly compute the resistance using Kirchoff laws,. If that's the answer you get, that's the answer you get. What do you mean by "Why?" .

Comment: I want some way of seeing that it is true without calculating explicitly. It does not seem very easy to calculate it exactly. My goal is approximate maximum resistance across any two nodes in the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is not entirely rigorous, since it avoids many convergence issues. But it gives a quick way to see why we expect a certain answer.

### Connections with Laplacian on the Graph

The problem of finding the effective resistance is tied to harmonic functions on graphs in the following way. Start with a graph $\mathcal{G}$. Each vertex represent a node and each edge represent a resistor with 1$\Omega$ resistance.

To find the effective resistance between two nodes, what we imagine is connecting a battery with voltage difference $V$ with the cathode to one of the nodes, and the anode to the other. By monitoring the current flow and using $V = IR$ we can compute the effective resistance.

If we allow ourselves to "change the battery until the current becomes $1A$, then numerically the voltage would be (in volts), the same as the effective resistance (in ohms).

Let $F:G \to \mathbb{R}$ be the map that tells you the potential (voltage) at each node.

Now, since the individual edge has a 1$\Omega$ resistor, the current flow between nodes $v_1, v_2$, assuming that they are connected, is precisely $F(v_1) - F(v_2)$ Amps. Kirchoff's law says that the net current at each node on the graph must be 0, except at the two terminals where the batteries connected (the connectors to the batteries are not drawn), where the net current flow is $\pm 1$. (By our assumption that the current flowing in and out of the battery is 1A).

This tells you that away from the two privileged nodes where you plug in the battery, the function $F$ must verify $LF = 0$ where $L$ is the [graph Laplacian operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Graphs).

(In other words, since $LF = \pm 1$ on the cathode and anode, we can write $F = F_+ - F_-$ where $F_+$ is the Green's function for $L$ on $G$ centered at the cathode , while $F_-$ is the Green's function for $L$ on $G$ centered at the anode.)

### Symmetrization

Our $G$ is a bounded graph with vertices $\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}^d$ representing a grid. We can divide up $\mathbb{Z}^d$ into rectangular subgrids. Now, we can get a periodic function (kind of like an [elliptic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function)) on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ by extending the function $F$ to a function $\tilde{F}$ on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ such that $\tilde{F}$ is **reflected** between adjacent subgrids. (These corresponds to our choosing *Neumann* boundary conditions when we constructed $F$.)

So why do we symmetrize?

$\tilde{F}$ can be regarded, by the principle of superposition, as 
$$ \tilde{F} = \sum F_{+,k} - \sum F_{-,k} $$
where $F_{+,k}$ is the Green's function for the graph Laplacian on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ centered at the $k$th reflected image of the cathode, and similarly for $F_{-,k}$. The good thing now is that $F_{+,k}$ is simply the *translation* of the graph Laplacian on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ centered at the origin, translated to center on the cathode. In other words, writing $g$ for the Green's function, we have 
$$ \tilde{F} = \sum g(v - v_{+,k}) - g(v - v_{-,k}) $$
where $v_{\pm,k}$ are the $k$th cathode and anode.

The advantage is that we have an okay idea what $g$ looks like; so our situation is improved compared to the case on a bounded domain where there is no clear relation between $F_+$ centered at two different points. (BTW this is related to the method of mirror charges in electrostatics.)

Using that we know $g$ to be roughly monotonic as you go outwards radially, you see that to maximize the potential difference you want to put the cathode as close as possible to its mirror reflections, and as far as possible from the anode. This leads to the conclusion that the maximum difference is obtained when the two nodes are opposite ends of a diagonal of $G$.

Comment: I think I made a mistake in my question, the potential difference seems to be minimum between the corner nodes(from some calculations). Is it possible you made a mistake in your final lines? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Are you sure? Look at the 2-by-2 case. The resistance between corners is 1. The resistance between adjacents are $1/ (1 + 1/3) = 3/4 < 1$.

Comment: Yes. ofcourse you are correct. I was being dumb!